# Laravel livewire filter product by category attributes

Tags: laravel, e-commerce, laravel-livewire, livewires

I am creating a eCommerce application, where product of each category has their own attributes and specifications, which can be filtered by the user.

| Product Category | Attributes |
| --- | --- |
| Desktop PC | Processor, Processor speed, RAM memory, Graphcis card, etc |
| Phones | Battery, Screen size, RAM, Memory |
| Televisions | Brand, Screen size, Color, |

Each category-based product has a set value of the specifications in the attribute_product table that has columns product_id, attribute_id and attribute_value.

In the class below I set if condition if some atributte is selected to filter

My SearchComponent class

```
class SearchComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $search = '';
    public $categoryId;
    public $filters = [

    ];

    public function mount($categoryId){
        $this->category_id = $categoryId;
    }

    public function render()
    {

        $q = Product::query();

        if($this->filters){
            $q->whereHas('attributes', function ($q) {
                foreach ($this->filters as $key => $values) {
                    $q->where(function($q) use ($key, $values) {
                        $q->where('attribute_id', $key)->whereIn('attribute_value', $values);
                       
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        $products = $q->where('category_id',$this->category_id)
            ->whereLike('name', $this->search ?? '')
            ->paginate(12);

        $specifications = Attribute::
            join('attribute_category','attributes.id','=','attribute_category.attribute_id')
            ->where('attribute_category.category_id',$this->category_id)
            ->select(['attributes.*'])
            ->get();
        
        return view('livewire.search-component',compact('products','specifications'));
    }
}
```

The product model has relationships BelongsToMany with a table attribute_product containing the set values attributes

My livewire search-component.blade

```
@foreach($specifications as $spec)
 <div class="sidebar-widget mt-30">
    <h4 class="pro-sidebar-title">{{ $spec->attribute_name }} </h4>
        @if($spec->type_id == "1")
          <div class="pro-sidebar-search mb-50 mt-25">
             <div class="pro-sidebar-search-form">
                 <input type="text" wire:model="filters.{{ $spec->id }}" placeholder="Search here..."  />
              </div>
          </div>
        @endif
        @if($spec->type_id == "2")
           <ul>
              <li>
                 <div class="sidebar-widget-list-left">
                     <input wire:model="filters.{{ $spec->id }}" type="checkbox" value=""> {{ $spec->attribute_name }}
                </div>
              </li>
           </ul>
        @endif
        @if($spec->type_id == "3")
           <select wire:model="filters">
                <option value="">Select {{ $spec->id}}</option>
                @foreach(explode(',',$spec->options) as $key=>$row)
                <option value="{{$row}}">{{ $row }}</option>
                @endforeach
           </select>
        @endif
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I get the error "count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string given" when I select any attribute to filter.

I tried some combinations but without success. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: does it tell you which line the error occurs on? That can help us point you in the right direction. Sometimes the error will be in the blade file and sometimes in the component.

Comment: @maximus1127 in SearchComponent $q->where('attribute_id', $key)->whereIn('attribute_value', $values) this error occurs. I changed whereIn to where, it does not show this error anymore, but does not filter products when I select a filter

Comment: @maximus1127 UPDATE: Filtering works for me but only when I select one filter, when I select multiple filters it does not work ie. displays an empty list of products. I think I'm missing something that either in search-component.blade.php or in SearchComponent.php class

Comment: Try diving into the source code of where the exception happens. Sometimes you just gotta mess around in the source code to find out what's happening. Perhaps a value you're passing isn't the right format.